# What are current tools to develop Desktop apps for 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, application-development, ide

Coming from Windows, I an used to being able to use Visual Studio to quickly layout a Desktop App, add in the event driven code and have a useful tool really quickly.

I am looking for something similar for Ubuntu 22.04. I tried searching but the NEWEST similar question I could find was from 9 years ago and a lot has changed in 9 years. The best suggestion I found was for "Mono Develop" but it doesn't seem to be in development anymore and latest IDE install instructions are for Ubuntu 18.04. I keep hearing about VS.Core but that doesn't seem to be for UI based applications. I read about "Quickly" but again seems to be abandoned.

I don't really care what the underlying programming language is. C#, VB, Java, JavaScript, Python, etc. If I don't know it, I can figure it out. I just need a way to quickly, easily, and visually layout a application, add in some code, and run/debug it. One thing it will need to be able to do, is prompt for root password when needed to edit protected files at run time.

So what is out there now that fits this bill and works for 22.04 and hopefully will be supported for a long time to come?

Comment: so you basically want a GUI for creating GUI apps?

Comment: "*hopefully will be supported for a long time to come*" asks us to predict the future, which is pure guesswork. Your own research has shown that promising projects get abandoned.

Comment: @Ester Basically yes. Something similar to Visual Studio on Windows, or the abandoned "Quickly" project on older versions of Ubuntu. I can't imagine that nothing like that even exists anymore. Seems like it would be a huge step backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many many hours of looking and digging, I think I found what I was looking for. Actually at this point I found 2 options.

What I am going with is Glade for UI design, Python for the language, and VS Codium (non-MS version of VS Code) for the semi-IDE. I initially planned on using Go as the language because it could also work with Glade and compiles into native binaries. But I couldn't get Go setup properly in Codium, so I went with Python. I chose this combo because I wanted to specifically target Gtk for Gnome based Desktops.

The other option I found and considered, was JavaFX with Scene Builder for the UI design, and any Java compatible IDE. I may even end up using this at some point if I want to make something more platform independent.

I hope this helps save someone else a lot of time looking for a similar setup in 2022.

Comment: NetBeans has been around for a long time. I see it's now maintained by the Apache org. I think it has forms design mode.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is on-topic here since not really specific to Ubuntu...but anyway.

There is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) that also runs on 22.04 (that's probably what you meant by "VS.Core"). There has been an issue with it crashing on launch when 22.04 initially came out, but with the latest updates and the latest VSCode version that is fixed. VSCode is language-agnostic, you can use it with whatever language or toolkit you want by installing the proper plugins.

Additionally I can recommend [QtCreator](https://www.qt.io/product/development-tools) if you want to develop apps with Qt.

Comment: You are correct, I meant VS Code, I mixed it up with .Net Core. I was under the impression that VS Code did not support any sort of Visual UI designer though. If it does, that would be amazing. I know you can create UI's in many languages via code, but I'm looking for more of a Drag and Drop UI Design, OR at least have some sort of realt time visualizer, if I am doing it via code.

Comment: In that case QtCreator or QtDesigner may be more your thing. I'm not much a fan of drag&drop UI design, I prefer doing it by numbers and for that VSCode is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Sebastian's reply:

Get familiar with the [XDG Desktop specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) and the [XDG Base Directory specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

For example, just like on Windows the recommended location to save config files is `%APPDATA%`, on Linux you should save your config files to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable, and if it's not set, you must default to `$HOME/.config`

Likewise there are standard locations for cache and log files.

Like on Windows, you don't *have to* follow those standard locations, but following them leads to a consistent user experience.

If you want to open a file using the registered MIME-type (like a PDF) you should use the `xdg-open` process. e.g. `xdg-open my_file.pdf` should open the registered PDF viewer.

As for Ubuntu-specific stuff; assuming you don't statically link, if you build your app on Ubuntu 18.04; it's likely that your app will work on 20.04 and 22.04 as well with the following gotchas:

- Library dependencies written in C tend to have a stable ABI. So if for Ubuntu "1" you use GTK 3.0 and Ubuntu "2" still has GTK 3.2; then due to semantic versioning it still should work
- But if the library dependency is in C++ and/or doesn't have a stable ABI (e.g. wxWidgets) then it's likely that your app will *only* work for the Ubuntu version it was linked for
- If Ubuntu "2" drops a package you depend on (e.g. completely drops GTK 3.x; introduces GTK 4), then of course your app will no longer run against that distro version unless you fix those broken dependencies and rebuild.

It also depends on whether you're targetting Ubuntu specifically. Since Ubuntu is mostly FOSS, open source software shold dynamically link everything so that deb package maintainers can sort out all the dependencies.

But proprietary SW often can't be rebuilt so they choose to statically link as much as possible (or use dynamic linking but bundling needed libs, sometimes using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) or use solutions like AppImage.

Valve has posted a [few videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sd8ie5R4CVE) online to [get started](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btNVfUygvio) on how to target Linux that you may be interested in.

Comment: Looks like extremely helpful information, but doesn't really answer the question, of what are the currently available Visual UI Designers/IDE's for Linux.